# Импорт из папки public в src reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, импорт

Всем привет!

Скажите, возможно ли безболезненно импортировать js файл из папки public, например, public/content/content.js, в папку src?

Есть простая детская игра, формата выберите подходящее слово, перетащите слово...и тд., созданная на react. Существует массив данных с этими словами, файл которого сейчас располагается в папке src, данный файл необходимо перенести в папку public, так как картинки связанные по смыслу (на конкретной картинке, отрисовываются слова, которые необходимо выбрать) с этим массивом находятся в папке public. Возможно ли как-то сделать импорт массива из папки public? В сети ничего подходящего к сожалению не нашел.